# Scala higher kinded types in implicit def fails with "could not find implicit value"

Tags: scala, implicit, higher-kinded-types

I'm using implicit def to build a recursive `HList` type, to match several kind of higher kinded types of `HList`. I'm heavily inspired by [this post](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.fr/2008/08/hlist-in-scala.html).

This code is working perfectly :

```
sealed trait HList {
  type Plus[L <: HList] <: HList
}

class HNil extends HList {
  type Plus[L <: HList] = L

  def ::[T](v: T) = HCons(v, this)
}

case class Appender[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, R <: HList](fn: (L1, L2) => R) {
  def apply(l1: L1, l2: L2) = fn(l1, l2)
}

object HNil extends HNil

object HList {
  def ++[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList](l1: L1, l2: L2)(implicit f: Appender[L1, L2, L1#Plus[L2]]): L1#Plus[L2] = f(l1, l2)

  implicit def nilAppender[L <: HList]: Appender[HNil, L, L] = Appender((v: HNil, l: L) => l)

  implicit def consAppender[T, L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, R <: HList](implicit f: Appender[L1, L2, R]): Appender[HCons[T, L1], L2, HCons[T, R]] = {
    Appender[HCons[T, L1], L2, HCons[T, R]]((l1: HCons[T, L1], l2: L2) => HCons(l1.head, f(l1.tail, l2)))
  }
}

case class HCons[T, U <: HList](head: T, tail: U) extends HList {
  type Plus[L <: HList] = HCons[T, U#Plus[L]]

  def ::[V](v: V) = HCons(v, this)
}

import HList._

val hlist1 = 2.0 :: "hi" :: HNil
val hlist2 = 1 :: HNil

val sum = ++(hlist1, hlist2)
println("last element : " : + sum.tail.tail.head) // prints last element : 1"
```

Now, I don't know why but if I try to add a `++` method on `HCons`, which simply calls existing `HList.++` method, this is NOT working :

```
 case class HCons[T, U <: HList](head: T, tail: U) extends HList {
 type Plus[L <: HList] = HCons[T, U#Plus[L]]

  def ::[V](v: V) = HCons(v, this)

  def ++[L2 <: HList](l2: L2) = HList.++(this,l2)
}
```

I get this compilation error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter f: Appender[HCons[T,U],L2,HCons[T,U]#Plus[L2]]
```

As `HCons` is a subtype of `HList`, like the L1 type defined by HList.++, I was thinking it was OK.

I've tried this but that's not working better :

```
implicit def consAppender[T, L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, L3, R <: HList](implicit f: Appender[L1, L2, R], ev: L3 <:< HCons[T, L1]): Appender[HCons[T, L1], L2, HCons[T, R]] = {
    Appender[HCons[T, L1], L2, HCons[T, R]]((l1: L3, l2: L2) => HCons(l1.head, f(l1.tail, l2)))
  }
```

What did I miss?

Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't try to follow what you're doing, but the `: HList` in line three is a red flag. `HList` is pretty much useless as a static type for anything.

Comment: Thanks, in fact it is overloaded by case classes inheriting from HList

Comment: I've removed it for less confusion but the behavior is the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should change your `++` method definition from this:

```
 def ++[L2 <: HList](l2: L2) = HList.++(this,l2)
```

to this:

```
def ++[L2 <: HList](l2: L2)(implicit f: Appender[HCons[T,U], L2, Plus[L2]]) = HList.++(this,l2)
```

The compiler doesn't have enough information to select the right implicit value inside the method definition, but when you pass the appender from the outside, this example should pass:

```
val hlist1 = 2.0 :: "hi" :: HNil
val hlist2 = 1 :: HNil
println(hlist1++hlist2)
```

*Update 1:* In the `++` method on `HCons`, we call the `HList.++` method which requires an implicit parameter. This parameter must be of type `Appender[HCons[T, U], L2, HCons[T, U#Plus[L2]]]`. The compiler could fill this implicit parameter from `HList.consAppender`, but this in turn requires another implicit parameter of type `Appender[U, L2, U#Plus[L2]]`. *This is the parameter that the compiler cannot discover itself*. Knowing this, the code above can be simplified to:

```
def ++[L2 <: HList](l2: L2)(implicit f: Appender[U, L2, U#Plus[L2]]): Plus[L2] = HList.++(this, l2)
```

*Update 2:* The compiler must fill in implicit parameters at the call site, in our case inside `HCons.++` method (can be verified, e.g., with `scalac -Xprint:typer`). It can choose from implicits providing two appender types:

```
Appender[HNil, L, L]
Appender[HCons[T, L1], L2, HCons[T, R]]
```

The first one can be used only if type parameter `U` is `HNil`, the other only when `U` is `HCons`. But this information is not available inside `HCons.++`. It only knows that `U <: HList` but doesn't know which implementation of `HList` it is and therefore fails.

Comment: Update 1 version is not working :   could not find implicit value for parameter f: Appender[HCons[T,U],L2,HCons[T,U]#Plus[L2]]

Comment: Not sure where's  the problem in that, it works for me (using Scala 2.11.6). We could dig into it deeper, but I'm happy as long as the first version is working for you.